# Avr assembly Y pointer

Tags: avr

If the Y pointer stores the address of the byte in memory it points to, how is the value stored at the location accessed?

```
.dseg ; Define a data segment
Cap_string: .byte 5 

main:
ldi yl, low(Cap_string)
ldi yh, high(Cap_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

The instruction to read from the location that a pointer is pointing to is called "Load Indirect" and looks like this:

```
ld r5, Y
```

In the example above, `r5` can probably be any register, and `Y` is the name of the pointer, and can be replaced with `X`, `Y`, or `Z`.

To write to the location, use the "Store Indirect" instruction, which is written like this:

```
st r5, Y
```

You can find more information in the [AVR Instruction Set Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf).

Comment: but will ld read the location for example 0X0200
OR will it read the value stored in that location

Comment: @Darrenrogers it *has* to read the *byte* from memory. `Y` is a 16-bit value; how should it read that value (like `0x0200`) into `r5`?

Comment: To be fair, my answer was initially worded in a confusing way.